# Convert from IEnumerable to String with OpenXML

Tags: c#, entity-framework, openxml-sdk

I want to get the values from the second column of an excel using OpenXML to Read it. What I save in my DB is this

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell,System.String]
```

But that column is a string. I use Entity Framework to insert in my table

```
foreach (Row r in sheet.Elements<Row>().Skip(1))
{
    db.Table.Add(new Table{
        Id= Convert.ToInt32(r.Elements<Cell>().First().CellValue.Text),
     Name= r.Elements<Cell>().Where(c=>c.CellReference=="B2").Select(x=>x.CellValue.Text).ToString()
    });
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Name is my second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Name= r.Elements<Cell>().Where(c=>c.CellReference=="B2").Select(x=>x.CellValue.Text).ToString();
```

Is causing the issue. Perhaps you want this:

```
Name= r.Elements<Cell>().Where(c=>c.CellReference=="B2").Select(x=>x.CellValue.Text).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```